# How to select data From data base using SQLite data base in java with multiple tables

Tags: java, sqlite, request

i'm using SQLite and i need to make a select from many tables and i'm working with java  my problem is when i make this select as result i have nothing it returns an empty arrayList .

```
 public void etapeParametrerOption(String login) throws IOException, SQLException
{
    assertTrue( "Texte 'Paramétrer les options' non présent, voir code source HTML dans LogOut",selenium.isTextPresent( "Paramétrer les options" ) );

   String [] tab=LogFile.showWSEtAppelCOffrEFrom(login);
  List<String>ls=new ArrayList<String>();

   for(String itab : tab){

       ls=dbCOffrE.executeSelect("SELECT busitypid,attblabel FROM t_article art, t_attribute att , t_srvbrick_attr_article srv WHERE att.attbid = srv.attbid and art.artid = srv.artid and att.modoptidmodifiable = '2' and (att.attbinactivationdate is null or att.attbinactivationdate < date('now')) and art.artshortlabel='"+itab+"'");

      logger.info("ma liste :"+ls);
   }


 public List<String> executeSelect( String ArgRequete, boolean All) throws SQLException
```

{

```
String ReturnColumn = ArgRequete.substring( ArgRequete.indexOf( "SELECT" )+ 6, ArgRequete.indexOf( "FROM" ) ).replaceAll(" ","");
List<String> Str = new ArrayList<String>();
logger.info("ret :"+ReturnColumn);
String[] columns=ReturnColumn.split(",");
for(String ico:columns){
 logger.info(ico);
```

}
   stmt = con.createStatement();

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery( ArgRequete );
logger.info(ArgRequete);

logger.info("mon resultSet:"+rs);
if ( !All )
{
    if ( rs.next() )
    {
        String result = "";
               for(String aColumn : columns){
                            result += rs.getString(aColumn ) + ",";
                            logger.info(result);

                }
                Str.add( result );
     }
}
while ( rs.next() && All )
{
                           String result = "";
                           for(String aColumn : columns){
                                       result += rs.getString( aColumn ) + ",";
                           }
    Str.add( result );
}
stmt.close();
return Str;
```

}

so when i use a simple  request like "Select S1 , S2 from NameTable where Id=  '345'"  it works perfectly but a request like this : 
 SELECT busitypid,attblabel FROM t_article art, t_attribute att , t_srvbrick_attr_article srv WHERE att.attbid = srv.attbid and art.artid = srv.artid and att.modoptidmodifiable = '2' and (att.attbinactivationdate is null or att.attbinactivationdate < date('now')) and art.artshortlabel='"+itab+"'") 
 it crashes actually .

and in my log file i have as result :
 INFO  com.sfr.price.functionalTest.commons.SQLBase.executeSelect []       ret:busitypid,attblabel
  INFO  com.sfr.price.functionalTest.commons.SQLBase.executeSelect [] busitypid
  INFO  com.sfr.price.functionalTest.commons.SQLBase.executeSelect [] attblabel
  INFO  com.sfr.price.functionalTest.commons.SQLBase.executeSelect [] SELECT busitypid,attblabel FROM t_article art, t_attribute att , t_srvbrick_attr_article srv WHERE att.attbid = srv.attbid and art.artid = srv.artid and att.modoptidmodifiable = '2'  and art.artshortlabel='8001P'
  INFO  com.sfr.price.functionalTest.commons.SQLBase.executeSelect [] mon resultSet:org.sqlite.RS@24c672
  INFO  com.sfr.price.functionalTest.scenario.impl.AJLINGE.etapeParametrerOption []    ma liste :[]

Comment: it doesn't work with join and the prepareStatement too  and i'm tired of finding a solution of this problem and it  always returns an empty ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the attached code does not correspond with the log file Your attached in You question. In the log file we can see that the following query gets executed:

```
SELECT busitypid,attblabel FROM t_article art, t_attribute att , t_srvbrick_attr_article srv WHERE att.attbid = srv.attbid and art.artid = srv.artid and att.modoptidmodifiable = '2' and art.artshortlabel='8001P'
```

And in the code fragment You have the following query

```
SELECT busitypid,attblabel FROM t_article art, t_attribute att , t_srvbrick_attr_article srv WHERE att.attbid = srv.attbid and art.artid = srv.artid and att.modoptidmodifiable = '2' and (att.attbinactivationdate is null or att.attbinactivationdate < date('now')) and art.artshortlabel='"+itab+"'"
```

Note the additional check of the att.attbinactivationdate in the WHERE clause. Maybe the query You actually execute doesn't return any values just as it should.